Network profile badges section not showing all my badges
Or at least- it's not showing them in order. I don't know. I'm not paging through every page to check. For example, I (somehow) earned 7 Announcer badges on June 5th and none of them show up in my network profile between the ones I earned before and after that day.

@testing-ma-lady oh just ignore that. it was me messing around a while ago and I just put it back to normal.
